# Uploading files to Sharepoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

i am trying to upload files to a Sharepoint Online document library.

can anybody help me in achieving this?  i have tried different scripts, but keep getting errors

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and where in your code you're having issues with?

Comment: Install the [SharePoint Online module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps) and then https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40048.sharepoint-20162013online-how-to-upload-files-to-sharepoint-document-libraries-by-powershell-automation.aspx

Comment: have a look there https://automatiz.it/2021/05/download-and-upload-files-from-teams-with-powershell/